# Insert Backbone.js model into MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js model with some defaults and an url:

```
var Box = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "./save.php",
    defaults: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        w: 1,
        h: 1
    }
});
```

Then I have an instance of this model and I proceed to save it:

```
var box = new Box({ x:10, y:10, w:200, h:200 });
box.save();
```

Now I want to save this model into a MySQL database using a PHP script "save.php", it goes like this:

```
<?php 
    include('connection.php');

    $id = $_POST['cid'];
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    $w = $_POST['w'];
    $h = $_POST['h'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO boxes (id, x, y, w, h)
                         VALUES('$id', '$x', '$y', '$w', '$h')
                       ") or die(mysql_error());
?>
echo "Data Inserted!";
```

I have tried reading many tutorials but I cannot get this simple model save to work. Why is my code not working? Any ideas on how can this be solved?

Thanks

**EDIT: QUICK SOLUTION**

In the php script, the correct way to obtain the information from the sent JSON object is as follows:

```
$box_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$x = $box_data->{'x'};
$y = $box_data->{'y'};
$w = $box_data->{'w'};
$h = $box_data->{'h'};
```

And to store in in the database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO boxes(id, x, y, w, h)
            VALUES('', '$x', '$y', '$w', '$h') ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

In this way one row will be inserted in the table "boxes" with the information of each one of the attributes of the backbone model Box.
The server request method in this case is POST and the id in the table "boxes" is set to auto-increment.

Comment: why don't you save it a JSON into one field? Would be extensible. Or a way better approach would be to use a document based database like CouchDB or MongoDB, where data is already saved as JSONs.

Comment: Do you see the Data Inserted message? Ca n you see that the request to the php file is being made? do you get any response at all?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Backbone is based on a REST API: when saving/updating a model to the server, Backbone will send it serialized as JSON in the request body with a `POST` our `PUT` request. From [Backbone.sync documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

> With the default implementation, when Backbone.sync sends up a request
>   to save a model, its attributes will be passed, serialized as JSON,
>   and sent in the HTTP body with content-type application/json.

This means that server-side you have to

- determine the type of request
- decode the serialized JSON

Something like this should get you started

```
$request_method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
$data = null;

switch ($request_method) {
    case 'post':
    case 'put':
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    break;
}

// print_r($data);

// note that mysql_* functions are deprecated
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
// inserting with a PDO object, assuming an auto incremented id
$sql = "INSERT INTO boxes (x, y, w, h) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(
    $data->x,
    $data->y,
    $data->w,
    $data->h
));
$id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

Check this page for a more thorough implementation of a REST API in PHP http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Comment: Thanks @nikoshr, however I am still failing at saving the model into the database. I have tried at least to see what the server receives using a switch case to the request_method and storing the result in a variable, but I do not see anything, the only thing I know is that the request method is GET. Can you please provide a simple code in which at least I can have access to the JSON sent object? Thanks.

Comment: @rpabon `box.save()` sends a `GET` request? Very strange. You can read the serialized JSON with `file_get_contents('php://input')` but that won't work with a `GET`. Can you check with Firebug or Chrome Inspector what your browser sends (query parameter, post parameters, request body)?

Comment: What I am doing now is using the same code that I posted on the question and then added <?php header('Location: ./save.php'); ?>, so I can with this see the request method and the JSON in the browser, I do not know if maybe this is affecting the outcome.

Comment: @rpabon `header('Location: ./save.php');` redirects the request, losing the request type and the JSON, that's why you have a `GET` and nothing else. Go back to your previous version, modify it with my code, and check the response. It will be invalid for Backbone, but at least you'll see something.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to send ID.

//$id = $_POST['cid'];

[image]

Make Id to AUTO_INCREMENT and remove from code:

> $id = $_POST['cid'];

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO boxes (x, y, w, h)
                         VALUES('$x', '$y', '$w', '$h')
                       ") or die(mysql_error());
```