# Backbone Sync return an empty $_POST array

Tags: php, javascript, rest, backbone.js, yii

I'm trying to do my first RESTful app with Backbone and Yii Framework. 
I had no problem with the GET methods but I'm stuck now with the POST method, to create a new element.

I have a Comment model in Backbone:

```
var commentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: "index.php/api/comments",
    idAttribute: 'id',

    defaults: {
        content: "Empty comment",
        status: 1
    }
});
```

In my view I add a function to create a new Comment passing the values from the relative form:

```
on_submit: function(e) {
            var new_comment = new Comment({author_id: this.$('#author_text').val(), content: this.$('#content_text').val(), post_id: this.$("#post_text").val(), status: this.$("#status_text").val()});

         new_comment.save();
        },
```

Looking the request with Firebug it seems all right, in the POST tab I can see all the values:

```
JSON            
author_id "7"   
content "Epic fail"
post_id "7" 
status "2"

Source 
{"content":"Epic fail","status":"2","author_id":"7","post_id":"7"}
```

But in my php Api the $_POST var is empty!

```
foreach($_POST as $var=>$value) {

     if($model->hasAttribute($var))
        $model->$var = $value;
     else
        $this->_sendResponse(500);
}
```

Anyone has some ideas? Reading the documentation of Backbone.Sync I understand that it should use POST for create request.

I found a workaround getting the values from:

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

but id doesn't feel right to me...

Thanks.

Comment: Something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930789/insert-backbone-js-model-into-mysql-database/10931092#10931092 ?

Comment: The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` value is "POST" so the values should be inside the $_POST array, I'm right?

Comment: No, the method is a POST, but the data is sent the HTTP body. It is not sent as a regular form would be with parameters set and a application/x-www-form-urlencoded as mime type. Check what is sent in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RK7LN/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Backbone.sync documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync),

> With the default implementation, when Backbone.sync sends up a request
>   to save a model, its attributes will be passed, serialized as JSON,
>   and sent in the HTTP body with content-type application/json.

which means you won't receive data in parameters like in a regular form post but in the body of the HTTP response.

You've got three options to deal with this behavior:

1. Modify your server code to understand REST requests, see [Insert Backbone.js model into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930789/insert-backbone-js-model-into-mysql-database/10931092#10931092) for example
2. See if [Backbone.emulateJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON) could answer your needs
3. Overwrite [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) and send the data to better fit your server

Comment: Well it seems that I made a wrong assumption. Thanks for the clarification, now I'll make some test and see what solution will fit better my app.