# Backbone - Picking up POST vs PUT on the server side using PHP

Tags: php, backbone.js

This is the sample Model I'm using:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'json.php',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
});
var user = new UserModel();
// Notice that we haven't set an `id`

console.log(user.isNew());
var userDetails = {
    name: 'Thomas',
    email: 'thomasalwyndavis@gmail.com'
};
// Because we have not set a `id` the server will call
// POST /user with a payload of {name:'Thomas', email: 'thomasalwyndavis@gmail.com'}
// The server should save the data and return a response containing the new `id`
user.save(userDetails, {
    success: function (user) {
        console.log(user.toJSON());
    }
})
```

On the server side (apache) I'm using php to pick up the data. This is clearly saving a new Model, but the $_POST variable is empty and the data is appearing in:

```
     file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Is there a $_POST variable should this data appear in? Perhaps it is a POST, but Backbone isn't creating a query string which means the $_POST variable would be empty. On the serverside, I can check the json data to see if it's a new object or not (by the presence of an id), but is there a way to tell the difference between put and post on WAMP? Perhaps the browser doesn't even support put and just posts anyway?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930789/insert-backbone-js-model-into-mysql-database/10931092#10931092

Comment: You should use the developer console of your browser (Tools > Console) to monitor the network activity and see what request is your browser sending.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774448/backbone-sync-return-an-empty-post-array/11775570#11775570 if you prefer

Comment: Thx again Niko. Your code is written well. Nice and easy to understand so it's in $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']. Good man.

Comment: ..and I see helpfully on a put the id of the object is in $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']. it's in the json object too obviously.