# Can't Save Backbone JS Model to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, backbone.js

I'm a beginner learning Backbone JS, and I'm having trouble saving my first test model to a MySQL database. Although the AJAX request is being sent from Backbone with the correct POST payload (according to the browser inspector), my PHP script on the backend seems to be receiving an empty array.

Here's the code for the model:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'backboneUserBackend.php',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
});

 var user = new UserModel(),
 userDetails = {name: 'Jim Smith', email: 'jimsmith@example.com'};

 user.save(userDetails, {success: function(user){
    console.log(user);
 }
});
```

And here is my PHP script:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
// @todo: replace deprecated mysql method w/ PDO connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

if (mysql_errno()) {
    exit('DB connect error: '.mysql_error());
}

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s')", $name, $email);

if (mysql_query($query)) {
    echo mysql_insert_id();
} else {
    exit('Error inserting record: '.mysql_error());
}
}
```

To test whether or not my PHP script was actually being executed via the AJAX request, I added this test to the top:

```
$fh = fopen("mytest_".time().".txt", "w");
ob_start();
print_r($_POST);
$payload = ob_get_clean();
fwrite($fh, $payload);
fclose($fh);
```

Whenever my Backbone model is saved, a new file is created, but the file contains an empty array. Any thoughts?

Note: I'm using Chrome. Also, I know that I should be using a simple root URL, such as "/user," in my Backbone model... I'm just using the "backboneUserBackend.php" script temporarily, for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone posts your model updates JSON encoded, not  the normal form  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, so I'd be surprised if the `$_POST` array worked. (PHP is not my normal server-side language, so they could have changed somethings since the last time I worked with PHP.)

It looks like the answer to your problem might be found in this question/answer: [Insert Backbone.js model into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930789/insert-backbone-js-model-into-mysql-database) .

Answer (score 0):

As @JayC mentioned, the POST data that Backbone sends is JSON in the request body, not as parameters. What you'll want to do is:

```php
$data = json_decode(http_get_request_body());
$name = $data->name;
$email = $data->email;

// DB stuff goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers do outline what is going wrong in your code. May I suggest, you look into using a php micro-framework, such as [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/), to help with your REST api. I just recently started learning backbone, and using slim has made the server side stuff a snap.

Once you configure slim, setting up your routes is as simple as:

```
<?php
  require '../lib/Slim/Slim.php';
  \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

  $api = new \Slim\Slim();

  $api->get('/users', function(){ //sql function });
  $api->get('/users/:id', function($id){ sql function });
  $api->post('/users', 'addUser');

  $api->run();
  //functions below
?>
```

I was doing it all on my own, and then realised that Slim takes much of the trouble out of the process.

For example getting the post data:

```
$user = json_decode($request->getBody());
```