# not getting POST data with application/json

Tags: php, ajax, json, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone, PHP(5.6) and Apache(2.4).

**Problem:** When posting data using Backbone's model.save() the $_POST array is empty on the server.

I know about different ways to fix this.

**Client way:** setting *Backbone.emulateJSON* to true or changing the Backbone source.
**Server way:** reading raw body instead of $_POST.

These work but they feel like hacks and in fact they end up being a bit inconvenient. 
Also, Backbone's doc says:

> If you're working with a legacy web server that can't handle requests encoded as application/json, setting Backbone.emulateJSON = true; will [fix it].

So it sounds like a server problem. How do I make my server non-legacy?

Comment: Is this because you can't handle PUT and DELETE methods? possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816274/ways-to-save-backbone-js-model-data

Comment: thanks but I don't believe it's related.

Comment: Did you check $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ? If it's not POST I don't think $_POST will populated.

Comment: the request method is recognized as POST but the array is empty

Comment: @galki There's no built-in way in PHP to access a JSON post (besides reading the raw data). Either use a library/framework  like Symfony to do the work or roll your own solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930789/insert-backbone-js-model-into-mysql-database/10931092#10931092

Comment: PHP does not handle Content-Type: application/json afaik. - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441786/post-to-php-from-node-js) - some Request handlers like in Symfony 2 seems to handle it though iirc.

Comment: Thank you! I must have misinterpreted the 'legacy web server' comment and this is correct behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments I realized this is correct behavior.

$_POST is for form data, while json data (application/json) should be gotten from the raw input.

Comment: To get the the `raw input` you need to `file_get_contents("php://input");`